# " ] " and " [ " are not being mapped properly with xsetwacom

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, xev, keycodes

i'm trying to map my drawing tablet buttons and the command to do that for my particular scenario is:

```
xsetwacom --set 'Tablet Monitor Pad pad' Button 1 "key a"
xsetwacom --set 'Tablet Monitor Pad pad' Button 2 "key b"
```

The output would be:

- pressing button 1 > types the letter A,
- button 2 > types the letter B, etc.

And this works great, no problems. But when i try to set "key ["  or "key ]"  the output i get is a key press of the number 8 or 9 respectively.

I tried the command XEV to find the keycode:

[image: XEV screenshot]

And it turns out `"bracketright"` is a thing, but setting this does exactly the same thing as `]` (outputs the number 9 instead of ])

i even tried the keycode (keysym?) of `0x5d`
same result. (outputs `9`)

I'm not sure what to try next.. anyone have any ideas?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with the DIGImend drivers (Which i have installed and are working) (my tablet is a Huion H640P if it helps..)

OH, i just thought of something that may help, my keyboard layout is English (UK). Dunno if that might mess with anything? I feel like the `XEV` would have caught that regardless, but i feel like it's worth mentioning.

---

**Edit:** Turns out it does have something to do with the keyboard language, I set my keyboard to US and the output of [ and ] work perfectly.

I checked XEV for the keycode and it's the same as before.

Is this a bug? and should i report it? if so, then where?

And is there a way to check the *actual* binding/keycode for `[` and `]` on the British keyboard layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! answering my own question, I found the solution!

I found a [similar question to mine over at superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/952889/xsetwacom-unable-to-bind-a-button-to-square-brackets). One of the answers suggested using Alt-Gr and 8 or 9 (Which, just so happens to be another funky way of typing [ or ] )

ALT_R was not accepted by xsetwacom, it would output:

`Warning: unable to map 'Alt_R' to a keycode.`

So i used `XEV` to figure out what the mapping was for Alt-Gr on my keyboard, it told me it was:

`keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift)`

so i set my buttons with the lines:

```
xsetwacom --set 'Tablet Monitor Pad pad' Button 2 "key +ISO_Level3_Shift +9"
xsetwacom --set 'Tablet Monitor Pad pad' Button 3 "key +ISO_Level3_Shift +8"
```

And wouldn't you know it, it worked. pressing my tablet buttons types [ or ].
I tested it in Krita and it does exactly as expected and changes the brush size.

I spent two days looking for this answer. I hope someone who has the same problem stumbles across this answer and it helps them too.